# API calling doesn't response in JSON and instead responses in some nonsense Data

Tags: api, go, binary

I'm trying to call an API in Go, and like below I declare my method and other things in order to get the response I require but the problem I'm facing is I don't know if I have a problem in my request or the response it return have a problem.

This is the function that I use too pass data and call API

```
func APICall(url string,method string,request string) []byte{
  payload := strings.NewReader(request)
  client := &http.Client {
  }
  req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
  req.Header.Add("Access", "application/json")
  res, err := client.Do(req)
  defer res.Body.Close()
  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
  return body
}
```

```
func Search(c *gin.Context) {
  url := "https://testapi-v3.iati.ir/Tools/Ping/*************"
  method := "POST"
  payload := "{\"Echo\":\"asd\"}"
  resAsByte := APICall(url,method,payload)
  fmt.Println(resAsByte)
  var v map[string]interface{}
  err := json.Unmarshal(resAsByte,&v)
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

by the way

```
err := json.Unmarshal(resAsByte,&v)
```

doesn't work and this is the binary response that I got

```
[171 86 114 77 206 200 87 178 82 74 44 78 81 210 81 242 12 112 76 73 41 74 45 46 6 138 152 152 233 25 153 152 234 25 155 235 25 26 27 43 213 2 0]
```

Comment: That is not "nonsense data"; that is you printing a byte slice as their code points. You can print its string representation by doing something like `fmt.Printf("%s", b)`. Anyway, you should provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: unfortuantley, i should give u a token for that, and for security reason, i'm not able to do that, but thanks for the answere

Answer (score 0):

Your `APICall` returns `[]byte`. So here you see a representation of `[]byte`.
You may convert `[]byte` to `string`:

```
var s = string(body)
```

Then print `s` and see a string.

Comment: when i try this method, it return �VrM��W�RJ,NQ�Q�
                pLI)J-.���������

Comment: That's an API response. Check it, pls. Possibly it requests some specific data. May be it uses some specific encoding. Try to dump all returned headers.

Comment: i tested it in postman and it works correctly, my entry data is JSON and my method is POST, and it works just fine, but even when i Generate a goLang native code from postman, the result it what i posted you up there, and JSON.marshal doesn't work either, by the way thanks.

Comment: No, i wrote it as a test, it doesn't matter